# Why did Moses command the Levites to go out to slay instead of bringing the idolaters to the court?

Tags: moshe-rabbeinu, beit-din-court, levites-leviyim, golden-calf-egel

After the Golden Calf worshipping, Moses commands the Leviites to go out and kill the infidels:

> וַיֹּאמֶר לָהֶם כֹּה־אָמַר ה' אֱלֹהֵי יִשְׂרָאֵל שִׂימוּ אִישׁ־חַרְבּוֹ עַל־יְרֵכוֹ
> **עִבְרוּ וָשׁוּבוּ מִשַּׁעַר לָשַׁעַר בַּמַּחֲנֶה**
> וְהִרְגוּ אִישׁ־אֶת־אָחִיו וְאִישׁ אֶת־רֵעֵהוּ וְאִישׁ אֶת־קְרֹבוֹ׃
> He said to them, “Thus says the LORD, the God of Israel: Each of you put sword on thigh, **go back and forth from gate to gate throughout the camp**, and slay brother, neighbor, and kin.” [Exodus.32.27](https://www.sefaria.org/Exodus.32.27?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=bi&with=Rashi&lang2=he)

There were only 3000 executed when the number of grown-up Levites was over 22 thousand.

Why did Moses (God?)<sup>1</sup> command them to slay in the camp instead of bringing them to justice in the court?

<sup>1</sup> *from Rashi in place I understand that God commanded to execute idolaters in general but not specifically in the camp in this case.*